# Removing script from document head with jquery takes a few seconds, how to make it instant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm using google maps in prod and in order to do so I need to add a script to my document head. That script contains the `google maps javascript api` key that my app is using.

The `API key` is loaded server side but will still appear if anyone does an inspect element. In order to prevent that (ish), I'm removing the script from head with `jquery`. However this takes a few seconds, and it's very easy to look for the API key before it disappears from the DOM. Is there a way to force it to be removed instantly so it only appears in head a fraction of second?

Here is **the code** I'm using:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

let isApiSetup = false
let googleMapScript

Vue.prototype.$googleMaps = () => {
  if (!isApiSetup) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        isApiSetup = true

        /* Resolve promise when google maps is loaded and remove script with API key from head */
        window.googleMapsInit = () => {
          delete window.googleMapsInit

          // Remove script from head, but it takes a while
          googleMapScript.remove()
          resolve()
        }

        googleMapScript = document.createElement('SCRIPT')
        googleMapScript.setAttribute(
          'src',
          `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.googleMapsAuthToken}&callback=googleMapsInit`
        )
        googleMapScript.setAttribute('async', '')
        googleMapScript.setAttribute('defer', '')
        document.head.appendChild(googleMapScript)
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Edit: to be clear, my key is already restricted. But apparently this doesn't prevent spoofing so I'm looking to harden the overall security.

Comment: `it's very easy to look for the API key before it disappears from the DOM` - removing the script instantly wouldn't prevent anyone from seeing the script being loaded, including the API key, in the browser console anyway - google API keys are valid for specified domains anyway, so, no need to keep your API key secret - unless you've made your API key valid *everywhere* (I don't think you can do that though)

Comment: any chance that you're using nuxtjs?

Comment: This is security through obscurity, which is useless and futile. Just do what you’re supposed to do and restrict how your API key is to be used: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#best_practice_list

Comment: Yes I'm using nuxt @isebarn

Comment: I haven't used this but you can try it https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-gmaps ... or you can import the script in the nuxt.config.js, under head: { script: [ src: '...blablabla googleapis...'] }

Comment: if you import the script in nuxt.config.js, I would reccomend using dotenv, and placing require('dotenv').config() at the top of nuxt.config.js, then you can use the key in the https://maps.googleapis.com blabla + googleMapsAuthToken

Comment: @isebarn I tried that as well but it still shows unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Use a [proxy](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#proxy_server) instead.

Basically you setup an endpoint on your server that will fetch the googleMapScript using the key only on the server, then serves the fetched script to your user. In your front-end use your server endpoint as the `src` of the `<script>`. This way the API key is never served to any end user, it is only contained in a back-end request sent from your server to the Google API server.

Comment: Alright, I see where you're going with this. Does sound promising. Do you have an exemple ? I'm not sure how or what I should return from the server side (I'm novice when it comes to web dev)

Comment: from the link I provided: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup & https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-web-services-proxy/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3